# Different screens on different monitors

Tags: java, screen

I am trying to make a JAVA project where when I connect my laptop to a tv screen, I can see a different screen on my laptop and a different screen on the tv screen.
To be more specific I want to see on my laptop screen some settings buttons that I do not want to be visible on the tv screen. Also on my tv screen I want the mouse to be invisible, but on my laptop screen I want to see the cursor.

Since I have no idea how to do this even after I googled it, I would appreciate it if you could give me some directions.

Should there be 2 different screens?

Is there a way to declare programmatically which frame component will be visible in witch screen?

Comment: You can check the size of the window and so choose where && when to add the components you need.Starting with javaFX is your next step....http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm